# Adding a line break in JavaScript (full calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

This is from **[Adam Shaw's FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)**...

How can I put a line break in here so that line two moves to the next line?

```
events: [
    {
    title: 'Line 1 - This is line 2...',
    start: '2013-11-07'
},
```

I tried adding one of these, `+'<br />'`, but it didn't work...

Thoughts?

Comment: depends on how the text gets shown

Comment: Maybe 'Line 1 - \n This is line 2...' but it depends on how the calendar handles the title param...

Comment: It looks like [**this**](http://jsbin.com/okUtupOw/1/) - See the event for November 7th... like that one.

Comment: Adding a \n works! see: http://jsbin.com/IZoCoJIy/1/

Comment: @sjkm - That worked. I thought that form of line break was deprecated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like I already said in my answer above: **adding a \n does the trick!**

see: http://jsbin.com/IZoCoJIy/1/

Comment: 7 more long minutes bud. Sorry... Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

eventRender and try to find a fc-title then append html

```
    events : [
                {
                    "title":"TCC-000004",
                    "id":"2",
                    "start":"2019-12-03 09:00:00",
                    "end":"2019-12-03 00:00:00",
                    "color":"#730058",
                    "status":"A",
                    "description":"Testing Description"
                }
            ],

    eventRender: function(event, element) {

        // To append if is assessment
        if(event.description != '' && typeof event.description  !== "undefined")
        {  
            element.find(".fc-title").append("<br/><b>"+event.description+"</b>");
        }
    },
```

Result 
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Can i revisit this in regards to the full calendar Jquery when being printed and is in multi page form the page breaks mumbles the events right at the point of breaking off into the next page. Is there a know fix for this?

Comment: I need to see an example of what you're talking about. This calendar works fine for me. I'd also recommend opening up a new question. You're likely to get more answers that way. Respond to this comment with a link to the new question. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704851/full-calendar-jquery-plugin-multipage-print-is-out-of-skew

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class with `white-space: pre-line;`.

When you create your event, add the paramater `className` with your class

CSS:

```
.eventWithComment: {
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Event:

```
calendar.addEvent({
title: "Title",
start: date,
end: date,
className: ['eventWithComment'],
})
```